# Angular authorization with redirect and jwt

Tags: angular, vue.js

There are two "sites" - `localhost 3000` and `localhost 4200`.

1. Enter login and password. If this is a buyer, redirect to 2. (we get a token jwt).
2. On this site, using a token jwt, make an automatic login.

Is it possible to implement this? (3000 for vue, 4200 for angular)

Comment: It is. What is the problem with this? Just redirect and pass a token through url. It doesnt' look good that a token cam appear in url and stay in browser history, would be better for a server to handle the redirection and providing a token to a site

Comment: @EstusFlask I just don't know how to do it. :( Maybe you have a little example/tutorial or something. (never did it before)